# Listing YouTube Subscribers Bug on YouTube Data API V3?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

## The situation

**I'm trying to list all subscribers of a channel I manage.**

This seems to be a fairly straightforward use case for the API. I'm using python to hit the `youtube/v3/subscriptions` endpoint with parameters:

- `part=snippet`
- `mySubscribers=true`
- `pageToken` (for pagination)

This works perfectly for several page iterations.

## The problem

At some point along the way, one of the calls for a page will return `404 SubscriberNotFound`. My best *guess* at the moment is that 404 is returned if a subscriber of my channel has their subscriptions set to private. Here's the full JSON response of that error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.subscription",
    "reason": "subscriberNotFound",
    "message": "The subscriber identified with the request cannot be found.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "channelId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "The subscriber identified with the request cannot be found."
 }
}
```

I'd be fine with skipping over those particular users, but that doesn't seem to be possible because I would need the next `pageToken` to skip that page. Notice how the response above only describes the error, i.e. no `pageToken`.

Because of this, **I'm unable to continue pulling subsequent pages and generate the list.**

## Doesn't seem to be caused by my code

To make sure it wasn't something wrong with my code, I matched the parameters of the failed call (including `pageToken`) in the API Explorer online and received the same response and lack of subsequent pageToken.

## Additional concern

It seems like the entire page worth of results will fail **even if only one of the users within it has subs as private** (or whatever's causing the 404). So even if the API still returned the next `pageToken` allowing me to skip the page, I'd also skip over users with available data too.

For example, if my `maxResults` are set to 50 and only 1 user causes the whole page worth of data to 404, then I'd be missing 49 subscribers I should have grabbed from that page.

A workaround in this case, however, would be to set `maxResults` to 1. That's less than ideal too (but again, skipping a page of any size if it fails like this can't be done right now).

## My main questions

1. Is there a way to essentially 'filter out' subscribers of my channel who have their subs set to private (or whatever causes the 404)? I can't seem to find anything in the docs. If there were a way to do this, it would avoid both problems altogether (either failing completely or unnecessarily skipping over 'good' data).
2. If there's no workaround for this particular issue, is there any way to generate a list of all my subscribers by some other method?

Thank you so much for your help!! I feel defeated haha.